# How to analyze perf.data of perf sched record

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduler, perf

I have collected some perf data using :

```
perf sched record –g
```

I need to analyze the perf.data generated by this command.

I am using following command for analysis:

```
perf report
```

I see multiple sched events :

```
62K sched:sched_switch                                                                                                  ▒
0 sched:sched_stat_wait                                                                                                 ▒
0 sched:sched_stat_sleep                                                                                                ▒
0 sched:sched_stat_iowait                                                                                               ▒
120K sched:sched_stat_runtime                                                                                           ▒
10 sched:sched_process_fork                                                                                             ▒
31K sched:sched_wakeup                                                                                                  ▒
10 sched:sched_wakeup_new                                                                                               ▒
873 sched:sched_migrate_task
```

After I open one of the events, I see something like :

```
+   80.00%     0.00%  ksmtuned  bash               [.] make_child
+   80.00%     0.00%  ksmtuned  libc-2.17.so       [.] __libc_fork
+   80.00%     0.00%  ksmtuned  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] stub_clone
+   80.00%     0.00%  ksmtuned  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] sys_clone
+   80.00%    80.00%  ksmtuned  [kernel.kallsyms]  [k] do_fork
+   10.00%     0.00%      bash  bash               [.] make_child
```

I am not able to interpret this information.
Following are the questions I have :

1) What are the first two columns showing % values ? 
2) Why don’t  the % values add up to 100 % ?
3) What is the significance of these numbers ?

Comment: Brendan Gregg's site may be helpful: http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html

Comment: Its a good tutorial but does not answer all my questions.

Comment: @maverick9888, why not use `perf sched` subcommands to analyze results of `perf sched record`? Check http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-sched.1.html and https://lwn.net/Articles/353295/ "[Announce] 'perf sched': Utility to capture, measure and analyze  scheduler latencies and behavior", 2009. Sched is not to use with `perf report`, but `perf.data` may be opened by `perf report`. What is your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`perf sched record` is special variant of perf, and I think it is more correct to use `perf sched` subcommands to analyze resulting `perf.data` file.

There is man page on `perf sched`: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/perf-sched.1.html

> ```
>        'perf sched record <command>' to record the scheduling events
>        of an arbitrary workload.
>
>        'perf sched latency' to report the per task scheduling latencies
>        and other scheduling properties of the workload.
>
>        'perf sched script' to see a detailed trace of the workload that
>         was recorded...
>
>        'perf sched replay' to simulate the workload that was recorded
>        via perf sched record. (this is done by starting up mockup threads
>        that mimic the workload based on the events in the trace. These
>        threads can then replay the timings (CPU runtime and sleep patterns)
>        of the workload as it occurred when it was recorded - and can repeat
>        it a number of times, measuring its performance.)
>
>        'perf sched map' to print a textual context-switching outline of
>        workload captured via perf sched record.  Columns stand for
>        individual CPUs, and the two-letter shortcuts stand for tasks that
>        are running on a CPU. A '*' denotes the CPU that had the event, and
>        a dot signals an idle CPU.
> ```

Also there is letter from 2009 which describe `perf sched` functionality:  https://lwn.net/Articles/353295/ "[Announce] 'perf sched': Utility to capture, measure and analyze  scheduler latencies and behavior" and the recommended usage of `perf sched record` results is `perf sched latency` not `perf report`:

> ... experimental version of a utility 
>   that tries to meet this ambitious goal: the new 'perf sched' family of 
>   tools that uses performance events to objective characterise arbitrary 
>   workloads from a scheduling and latency point of view.
>
> 'perf sched' has five sub-commands currently:
>
> ```
>   perf sched record            # low-overhead recording of arbitrary workloads
>   perf sched latency           # output per task latency metrics
>   perf sched map               # show summary/map of context-switching
>   perf sched trace             # output finegrained trace
>   perf sched replay            # replay a captured workload using simlated threads
> ```
>
> Desktop users would generally use 'perf sched record' to capture a trace 
>   (which creates perf.data), and 'perf sched latency' tool to check 
>   latencies (which analyzes the trace in perf.data). The other tools too 
>   use an already recorded perf.data.

Comment: It doesn't answer my question completely, still accepted since it was very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @maverick9888, you just try to use wrong command, `perf report` is for parsing statistical profiles, but sched is variant of tracing profile. So report will be unable to correctly compute overhead (percent fields).

Comment: My scenario is a bi tricky.
In my application there is a rendering loop. And randomly one of the iteration takes more time (~1000 micro seconds).
I wish to collect data for this exact 1000 microsecond interval.
Is there a way I can put fences while taking perf measurements ?
i.e. split a 1 sec perf data linearly into 1000 * 1000 parts ?

Comment: @maverick9888, Can you log in your application exact moment of time (call `gettimeofday()` at the end of frame rendering and print that time with ns to some file) when the frame rendering was slow? Then you will be able to find that moment in `perf sched script` output. Also, you can try some tracing solution (there are many, listed in http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2016-12-27/linux-tracing-in-15-minutes.html), for example, lttng (it can trace both kernel events like scheduler and userspace tracepoints - lttng-ust, defined by you, for example moment of frame render start and end).

Comment: @osgx: I used your idea to log time from the application and try to match it with the timestamps in the perf data. The time gap is huge between the application timestamps and the perf timestamps. For example, first timestamp in perf data is 177898.937847 sec while the timestamp in application at the time of perf launch is 177829.251676. I ran the perf tool for 1 second. After the perf tool finished, I killed my application. The last time reported by the application is 177830.617393. The last timestamp from the app is behind first timestamp in the perf data. Can we co-relate these timestamps?

Comment: @maths-help-seeker, can you create minimal example of you problem (small program which for example will do 3-4 loops of `print timestamp, sleep for 1 s` and instruction of recording / displaying with `perf`) and create separate new question about timestamp differences? (you may add link to it here in new comment). There can be some problem in meaning of timestamp; also `perf` may not write part of tracing to `perf.data` when it was killed or application was killed.